# Using dependency injection with action composition

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

I am using Play framework 2.4 and creating a new authentication action which makes use of a custom Cache (which in turn uses the play CacheApi)

I can not, using any of the action composition methods, get dependency injection to work in order to have it invisible to my controllers.

My controller should look like:

```
class Application extends Controller {
  def index = AuthenticatedAction {
    Ok("You are authenticated! :D")
  }
}
```

And currently my Action looks like:

```
object AuthenticatedAction extends ActionBuilder[Request] {

  //val cache: ICache

  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
    request.cookies.get("authenticated") match {
      case Some(cookie) => {
        //How do I create a cache?
        //cache.hasCookie(cookie) match {
        //  case Any => block(request)
        //  case None => Future.successful( Unauthorized("No!"))
        //}

        block(request)
      }
      case None => Future.successful( Unauthorized("No!"))
    }
  }
}
```

I have a cache type ICache, but I can not inject that into the cache val in any way

Comment: You can't use dependency injection and also have it completely invisible to the controller-- that's kind of the point. You could inject an `ICache` into the controller and pass that to the action (implicitly if you like).

Comment: @dwickern _implicitly if you like_ How would I go about doing it that way?